# Getting sum of a column that needs a distinct value from other column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this table where I wanted to get the sum of the `balance` column but each item should have a unique value from the `date` column.

I'm trying to find all the rows in the `balance` column that are the same and have the same `date`, and then find the sum of the `balance` column.

sample data with unique dates:

| balance | date |
| --- | --- |
| 700 | 2021-07-03 |
| 700 | 2021-09-03 |
| 300 | 2021-09-04 |
| 500 | 2021-09-05 |

query used goes like:

```
select distinct a.balance, a.date from table a where a.date between (some date) and (some other date)
```

I have tried:

```
select sum(a.balance), a.date from table a where a.date between (some date) and (some other date) group by a.date
```

but the `balance` column shows the sum of **all** of the values in the column but shows distinct dates as shown below.

| balance | date |
| --- | --- |
| 893938 | 2021-07-03 |
| 858585 | 2021-09-03 |
| 728366 | 2021-09-04 |
| 665322 | 2021-09-05 |

Comment: (1) MySQL <> Oracle.  Please tag correctly.  (2). Your `GROUP BY` should do the right thing.  (3) Perhaps your sample data does not actually illustrate what you want to do.  Where does `858585` come from?

Comment: 858585 is the sum of all the values in the balance column that has the date 2021-09-03. I'll edit my question.

Comment: Show the actual raw data for the test case.  You could have 100's of rows containing a 700 balance for some date.  Try the following to understand the data a little better: `select a.balance, a.date, COUNT(*) AS n from table a where <some criteria> GROUP BY a.balance, a.date;`

Comment: If you just want the `SUM` of the `DISTINCT` balances per date, you could: `SELECT a.date, SUM(DISTINCT balance) AS dbal FROM tbl a ... GROUP BY a.date;`  I'm not sure why you would do this.  But that's how it could be done.

Comment: You should be **very carefull** before you `SUM` the *balance*, you typically sum the *transaction amount*, but not the *balance*....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is a job for a subquery. So let's take your problem step by step.

> I'm trying to find all the rows in the balance column that are the same and have the same date,

This subquery gets you that, I believe.  It give the same result as SELECT DISTINCT but it also counts the duplicated rows.

```
                SELECT COUNT(*) num_same_rows, balance, date
                  FROM `table`
                 WHERE a.datum BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2021-09-01'
                 GROUP BY date, balance
```

> and then find the sum of the balance column.

Nest the subquery like this.

```
SELECT SUM(balance) summed_balance, date
  FROM (
                SELECT COUNT(*) num_same_rows, balance, date
                  FROM `table`
                 WHERE a.datum BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2021-09-01'
                 GROUP BY date, balance
       ) subquery
 GROUP BY date
```

If you only want to consider rows that actually have duplicates, change your subquery to

```
                SELECT COUNT(*) num_same_rows, balance, date
                  FROM `table`
                 WHERE a.datum BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2021-09-01'
                 GROUP BY date, balance
                HAVING COUNT(*) >= 1
```

Be careful here, though. You didn't tell us *what* you want to do, only *how* you want to do it. The way you described your problem calls for discarding duplicated data before doing the sums. Is that right? Do you want to discard data?

Comment: Essentially, what I'm trying to do is look for duplicates in the `balance` column that have a similar `date` and find their sum.

Answer (score 0):

2nd query you posted looks OK - sort of.

However, I *think* that it is the fact that date column contains not only date, but also time (as `DATE` datatype in Oracle does). Therefore, I'd say that it is `trunc` you need. Something like this:

```
  SELECT TRUNC (a.datum) datum,
         SUM (a.balance) sum_balance
    FROM table_a a
   WHERE a.datum BETWEEN DATE '2021-01-01' AND DATE '2021-09-01'
GROUP BY TRUNC (a.datum)
```